# Wait programm close to keep an action by batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Just made this script below:

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 48,12
title BACKUP TEST
:test
cls
tasklist /fi "imagename eq test.exe" 2>nul | find /i /n "test.exe">nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo Encerre o Test para continuar...&echo.&pause&cls&goto test

if exist "C:\xxxxx\xxxx\BACKUP TEST\BKP TEST %date:/=.%.rar" goto end
echo Backup do banco iniciado...
set winrar="C:\Program Files\winrar"
%winrar%\winrar.exe a -ibck -ep1 "C:\xxxx\XXXXX\BACKUP TEST\BKP TEST  %date:/=.%.rar" "C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\TEST_BD0.FDB"
cls

if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
echo Backup do banco de dados realizado com sucesso
echo em %date% …s %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%h
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
)
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
echo. 
echo Falha ao realizar o bakcup...
pause
exit
)
exit
:end
echo O backup do banco de dados de %date% 
echo ja existe.
echo.
echo.
echo Por seguran‡a fa‡a o backup manualmente.
echo.
echo.
pause
```

I have to close `Test.exe` and then press some key for the script keep going. I just wanted close `Test.exe` and the script keep going automatically without pressing any key.
There's a way for it?

Comment: There might be helpful information from the `TASKKILL.EXE /?` command.

Comment: Take the pause out.

Comment: @Squashman, worked! But it is 'flashing' the screen because its returning by goto. I just want the screen stopped with echo "Waiting program close..." until the program be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
mode 48,12
title BACKUP TEST
tasklist /fi "imagename eq test.exe" 2>nul | find /i /n "test.exe">nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (echo Encerre o Test para continuar...)
:test
tasklist /fi "imagename eq test.exe" 2>nul | find /i /n "test.exe">nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (goto test)

if exist "C:\xxxxx\xxxx\BACKUP TEST\BKP TEST %date:/=.%.rar" goto end
echo Backup do banco iniciado...
set winrar="C:\Program Files\winrar"
%winrar%\winrar.exe a -ibck -ep1 "C:\xxxx\XXXXX\BACKUP TEST\BKP TEST  %date:/=.%.rar" "C:\XXXXX\XXXXX\TEST_BD0.FDB"
cls

if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
echo Backup do banco de dados realizado com sucesso
echo em %date% …s %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%h
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
)
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" (
echo. 
echo Falha ao realizar o bakcup...
pause
exit
)
exit
:end
echo O backup do banco de dados de %date% 
echo ja existe.
echo.
echo.
echo Por seguran‡a fa‡a o backup manualmente.
echo.
echo.
pause
```

**Removed the** **`pause`**. Credits To [*Squashman*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman).

I also **simply added `goto` loop while also using `tasklist` before the "test" loop so it checks and `echo`'s the text once if the task is there (*So it doesn't flicker and gets stopped as required by*)** [**Lalalalala**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10355019/lalalalala) in OP's Comment's Section and my Answer Comment Section.

Comment: Din't worked how i expected. The batch need wait the `test.exe` closes and automatically keep going. It must wait i close `test.exe`

Comment: Ok, but can't be this way, because it firstly need recognize if the `test.exe` is really running, so then show the `echo Encerre o Test para continiar`. The way you did, will show it even `Test.exe` is closed

Comment: And there's a way to set a progress bar in the batch screen when the winrar are compating the file?

Comment: Just added two `tasklist /fi "imagename eq test.exe" 2>nul | find /i /n "test.exe">nul` one for say `echo Encerre Test para continuar...` and another to loop until `test.exe` be closed. Worked fine also!